# Can I specify puppet's root execution directory at 'puppet apply' runtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet

Suppose I'm working in AWS, and have an EBS volume attached to an instance. That volume is a copy of a root volume, insofar as it was created by snapshotting the root volume of another instance.

I'd like to run puppet against my EBS volume, but not hardcode its mounted path into my puppet manifests. Suppose it were mounted at `/tmp/new-root-vol`. Is there any way to run puppet apply against that path without specifying it in the manifest itself?

To put it another way, how could I get this manifest snippet to create `/tmp/new-root-vol/testfile` without knowing the `/tmp/new-root-vol` namespace until runtime?

```
file {'testfile':
  path    => '/testfile',
  content => 'Hello, volume'
}
```

One possibility might be `chroot`. This [feature request](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/661) suggests it might work, as long as the puppet executable were accessible from the new root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way you can do that. However you can create a variable in your site.pp (or include another manifest like constants.pp) and use a variable:

site.pp

```
$root_dir = '/'
node default {
  include your_manifests
}
```

You file

```
file {'testfile':
  path    => "${root_dir}testfile",
  content => 'Hello, volume'
}
```

You could even change the root directory per node too.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of creating a custom fact or hiera variable or what have you. Unfortunately, I don't think this will work for user declarations and the like, but it seems like it's got promise.